# Keypress detection wont work after seemingly unrelated code change

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard

I'm trying to have the Enter key cause a new 'map' to generate for my game, but for whatever reason after implementing full-screen in it the input check won't work anymore. I tried removing the new code and only pressing one key at a time, but it still won't work.

Here's the check code and the method it uses, along with the newMap method:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    // ...

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // ...

        // Check if Enter was pressed - if so, generate a new map
        if (CheckInput(Keys.Enter, 1))
        {
            blocks = newMap(map, blocks, console);
        }

        // ...
    }

    // Method: Checks if a key is/was pressed
    public bool CheckInput(Keys key, int checkType)
    {
        // Get current keyboard state
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
        bool retType = false; // Return type

        if (checkType == 0)
        {
            // Check Type: Is key currently down?
            retType = newState.IsKeyDown(key);
        }
        else if (checkType == 1)
        {
            // Check Type: Was the key pressed?
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(key))
            {
                if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(key))
                {
                    // Key was just pressed
                    retType = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Key was already pressed, return false
                    retType = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Save keyboard state
        oldState = newState;

        // Return result
        return retType;
    }

    // Method: Generate a new map
    public List<Block> newMap(Map map, List<Block> blockList, Console console)
    {
        // Create new map block coordinates
        List<Vector2> positions = new List<Vector2>();
        positions = map.generateMap(console);

        // Clear list and reallocate memory previously used up by it
        blockList.Clear();
        blockList.TrimExcess();

        // Add new blocks to the list using positions created by generateMap()
        foreach (Vector2 pos in positions)
        {
            blockList.Add(new Block() { Position = pos, Texture = dirtTex });
        }

        // Return modified list
        return blockList;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I never touched any of the above code for this when it broke - changing keys won't seem to fix it. Despite this, I have camera movement set inside another Game1 method that uses WASD and works perfectly. All I did was add a few lines of code here:

```
private int BackBufferWidth = 1280; // Added these variables
private int BackBufferHeight = 800;

public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = BackBufferWidth; // and this
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = BackBufferHeight; // this
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true; // and this
}
```

When I try adding text to be displayed in the event the key is pressed, it seems that the If is never even triggered despite the correct key being pressed.

It seems that when the CheckInput method attempts to check for 'Enter' having just been pressed, it passes the first check `if (newState.IsKeyDown(key))` (which returns true) but fails the second `if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(key))` check. (and returns true, but shouldn't)

Comment: I've edited your main code (much shorter, wouldn't you agree?). Have a look at the 2 variables, put the breakpoint, and let me know what happens. (well,once the update is authorized that is :))

Comment: I saw your edit was rejected, but nevertheless, I've tested the code with the suggested breakpoints - it still won't work, but the debugging variables seem to be fine. Do note that the CheckInput method is being called every frame, not when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a line to the Update method as opposed to relying on it being updated during the CheckInput method.

Updated methods:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // ...

    if (CheckInput(Keys.Enter, 1))
    {
        blocks = newMap(map, blocks, console);
    }

    oldState = Keyboard.GetState();

    // ...
}

// Method: Checks if a key is/was pressed
public bool CheckInput(Keys key, int checkType)
{
    // Get current keyboard state
    KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
    bool retType = false; // Return type

    if (checkType == 0)
    {
        // Check Type: Is key currently down?
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            retType = true;
        }
        else
        {
            retType = false;
        }
    }
    else if (checkType == 1)
    {
        // Check Type: Was the key pressed?
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(key))
            {
                // Key was just pressed
                retType = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Key was already pressed, return false
                retType = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return result
    return retType;
}
```

Although I'm not entirely sure how this makes it work (especially considering it worked without this modification before) it's a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**Rolling answer, updated**

Here's how I would have wrote your code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    // ...
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // ...
        // Check if Enter was pressed - if so, generate a new map
        if (CheckInput(Keys.Enter, 1))
        {
            blocks = newMap(map, blocks, console);
        }
        // ...
    }

    // Method: Checks if a key is/was pressed
    public bool CheckInput(Keys key, int checkType)
    { 
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();   // Get current keyboard state
        bool retType = false;                           // Return type

        var debug_new = newState.IsKeyDown(key);
        var debug_old = oldState.IsKeyDown(key);

        if (checkType == 0)         // Check Type: Is key currently down?
        {
            retType = newState.IsKeyDown(key);
        }
        // Should happen only once, if key wasn't pressed before
        else if (checkType == 1 && newState.IsKeyDown(key))    
        {
            // Key pressed, wasn't pressed last update  -> true. 
            // Key pressed, but was pressed last update -> false.
            retType = !oldState.IsKeydown(key); 
        }

        oldState = newState;            // Save keyboard state

        return retType;                 // Return result
    }
    // ...
}
```

It's shorter and easier to read.

---

Now, when/how is your update method called from? does it happen when you hit a key? is it in a loop?

Next, If you remove (or comment out) the things you changed (in the 3rd code block), does it work?

Next, if you put a break point in your `CheckInput`, does it stop there everytime you hit a key?

Hopefully from there you'll be able to get some more help.

**Edit:**

Ok, lets see, when/why would you call the method with a `CheckInput(key, 0)` ?
Are you trying to avoid a double press of the Enter for example? (what's the point of those checks?)

**Another edit:**
Yep, I know it's being called every frame and not keypress. The only problem is I don't know know how often is that ... 60 fps vs 5 fps is a big difference.
Was wondering if there's any chance it gets out of sync somehow ... What I would have done is set a conditional debugging point there, to break on `Enter` pressed, released, and have a good look at your `newState` / `oldState`, to make sure the logic works the way you want (easier with the shorter code I believe :)

Comment: First; It is automatically called every frame. Second; If I comment them out, nothing changes. Third; It stops there, but it appears to pass the first 'check' (Is the key currently down?) but fails the second check that should return false (Was the key down last check?) but for some reason returns true. I've added some to the question.

Comment: In response to your edit, the purpose of the 0 method is for things like movement where 'true' should be able to constantly return if the button is held. 1 is for any time the button should only activate upon being pressed in the first place. Also, was way ahead of you on the code-shortening part - already got that.

Comment: It's easy to be ahead of me, I don't have your code :). Now, How about you edit your question with the updated code then? Remove the 2nd box which doesn't matter as far as I can see, and then we might pin point your woes with the keypress detection (assuming you care, if not, since you have your solution, you can just leave it :)

Comment: Done and done. Despite having a solution, knowing why the problem occured is useful information I'd very much like to know.